# Float certain list items right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css-float, listitem

I'm currently using bootstrap for the navigation bar, I have changed some things so it looks different. But I want to align 2 list items to the right side of the ul.

I have searched but I can't really find a working solution. Also keep in mind that I still want navigation bar to be fully responsive.

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

        <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>

        <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Video Library</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Orphanages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">The collective</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
                <li class="donate"><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope you guys can help me figure out how to do this. Thanks

[image: What I have]

[image: What I need]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the best solution is to split your links list in two:

```
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Video Library</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Orphanages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">The collective</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">What we do</a></li>
       </ul>
       <ul class="nav pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">Partners</a></li>
            <li class="donate"><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
       </ul>
```

You could also add `pull-right` only to the correspondent `li`, but you'd need to modify the `width` of the `ul` for that to work.